# Use Cauchy-Bolzano or Darboux

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function. Prove that $\exists c\in(a,b)$ so that 
>   $$f(c)=\frac{1}{a-c}+\frac{1}{b-c}.$$

I tried to take another function like $g(x)=f(x)-f(c)$ and calculated the limits from $x \to a$ and $x\to b$. I don't think this will work. Any other ideas?
Also I'm pretty sure this should be solved using Cauchy-Bolzano or Darboux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider the function
$$F(x):=f(x)-\frac{1}{a-x}-\frac{1}{b-x}$$
which is continuous in $(a,b)$ and evaluate the limits
$$\lim_{x\to a^+} F(x)\quad\mbox{and}\quad \lim_{x\to b^-} F(x).$$ 
Then apply the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (or [Bolzano's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html)).

Comment: How did you know that I should consider F(x) ? And why is it equal to that?

Comment: Your equation is $f(x)=\frac{1}{a-x}+\frac{1}{b-x}$ or $f(x)-\frac{1}{a-x}-\frac{1}{b-x}=0$ where $x$ is unknown.

Comment: BTW What is $\lim_{x\to a^+} F(x)$? What is $\lim_{x\to b^-} F(x)$?

Comment: First one is $\infty$ and the second is $-\infty$

Comment: Correct. So what may we conclude?

Comment: We conclude that there exists a F(c)=0 ?

Comment: Yes! One limit is $+\infty$ then $F$ attains a positive value "near" $a$.
The other limit is $-\infty$ then $F$ attains a negative value "near" $b$. By continuity, in between, there should be a value $c$ such that $F(c)=0$.